# Google maps, passing "map" to a different event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 different events, please correct me if i am doing this wrong,

```
    //initializing the map
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    //initializing the markers
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', showMarkers);
```

The first event is to initialize the map (set it up), the second event is for querying the database for new markers when the current map bounds change (not functional yet)

Since I have defined "map" inside the initialize function, how can I access it outside the function and pass it to the second event? As you can see i have declared it before the functions as a global variable but it is still undefined as the event argument, i have been stuck on this for days

```
var map;
function initialize(){
        //defining map options
        var mapLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -100.712891);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: mapLatlng
        }
        //defining the map itself
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    function showMarkers(){

        Parse.initialize("X","X");

        var query = new Parse.Query("business_and_reviews");
        var results = new Parse.Object("business_and_reviews");

        query.equalTo("name","McDonalds");

        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                console.log(results);

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];
                }

                var lat = (object["attributes"]["lat"]);
                var lng = (object["attributes"]["lng"]);

                console.log(lat);
                console.log(lng);

                //adding the marker from the query
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: mapLatlong,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });

            },
            error: function(object, error) {
            }
        });

    }
    //initializing the map
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    //initializing the markers
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', showMarkers);
```

For the second event "map" is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOlved it! put the idle event listener inside the initialize function and it works like a charm! I guess initilize isn't to initialize the page initially but runs constantly